# Grub can't detect Windows10 and its disk

Tags: linux, kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot with Kali Linux and Windows 10. Then I installed Kali on the disk D (D: ) and Windows 10 is on the disk C (C: ). 
I installed Kali successfully, but grub can't detect the disk C (which has my Windows 10 installed) and I am not able to boot with Windows 10 now. In other words, I am stuck in Kali now. 
I have tried

```
os-prober
```

but it doesn't show anything.
Also, I have updated the grub a few times but nothing changes.
Then, I use boot-repair to re-install grub but still, nothing changes.
The command `lsblk` and GParted can't detect the disk C too.
So, I try to open BIOS and enable the secure boot then it should boot with Windows 10 again (I hope). However, I am not able to access BIOS that it only shows a black screen.
I have no idea what to do now.

--------EDIT--------

Hi all, here is my output of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 493.7G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0 429.5G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Link to the report from boot-repair:http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PCdNQ2FbT7/

I am trying the solution provided by telcoM, I hope everything would be fine.

Comment: So is "disk D" a separate hard drive or was it a partition? Could you please update your post to include the output of `lsblk`? Thank you.

Comment: If you used Boot-Repair, post the pastebin site link to the Summary report it creates.

Comment: Linux can't read a Windows disk prepared as Dynamic. Please make sure in Windows using Disk Management your drive is a Basic Disk, not Dynamic.

Comment: Disk D is a separate hard drive which supposes to have Kali Linux installed on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with classic BIOS, Windows 10 requires a small "system partition" (sized 100 MB or greater) *in addition to* the main Windows partition. 
See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions

This system partition contains the Windows 10 bootloader... and when installing Windows on a system with multiple disks, the installer has a quirk that it very often doesn't place this partition on the same disk as the main Windows partition. As a result, it is possible that your system partition was on your Disk D: and got overwritten when you installed Kali.

This system partition is also what `os-prober` looks for when detecting Windows 10, so this would also explain why it does not detect your Windows.

You might want to temporarily disconnect your Disk D:, then boot from Windows 10 installation media and select "Repair your computer" in the bottom left corner of the first window. Perhaps the "Startup Repair" function will be able to re-create the missing system partition to your Disk C:, so it won't interfere with your Kali installation.